# Why can RSA-OAEP padded mail be decrypted using OpenSSL 1.0.1e?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I have been encrypting messages and specifying RSA-OAEP padding with OpenSSL 1.0.2k, using the following command:

```
openssl cms -encrypt -in content.txt -out message.msg \
-recip public-key.pem -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep
```

And can decrypt them fine when still using v1.0.2k.

When trying to decrypt the message in an environment using OpenSSL 1.0.1e, I would expect that decryption would fail, as on the documentation for OpenSSL cms, it says:

> Support for RSA-OAEP and RSA-PSS was first added to OpenSSL 1.1.0

However when I use the following command to try and decrypt the message (this would be within the v1.0.1e environment), the message is decrypted successfully and displays the original plaintext content.

```
openssl cms -decrypt -in message.msg -recip \
recipient-combined-key.pem -inkey private-key.pem
```

I would expect decryption to fail in this case, as surely the version without support for RSA-OAEP would have no knowledge of the padding scheme used?

I have also tested signed messages using RSA-PSS padding, and in that case the signature cannot be verified on the older version of OpenSSL without RSA-PSS support. Can someone explain why this is the case for PSS padding, and not OAEP padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.0.1 supports both OAEP and PSS padding modes, it is the `cms` tool that doesn't. Using `cms` to decrypt with OAEP padding works in 1.0.1 incidentally because the decryption function `cms` calls automatically determines the padding mode. The function called to verify a signature doesn't do this and defaults to PKCS1, so it fails.

The `cms` tool was [updated](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/e365352d6a6368039392fed14a328f8c0bf955c3) in 1.1.0 to, among other things, allow the `-keyopt` option so that padding can be specified when encrypting or signing, and to determine the padding type when verifying. This change was [backported](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/f2edf3181e30413c99864e7106125be7da905678) to 1.0.2.